# How to resolve 2 conflicting JavaScript files?

Tags: javascript

How to resolve 2 conflicting, separate, linked JavaScript files without using JQuery or any other external library or resource?

Comment: What exactly does it mean for javascript files to 'conflict'? Could you provide an example of two files conflicting and an explanation as to why/how they conflict?

Comment: how would jquery help? jquery usually causes problems, not solves

Comment: I still think your question isn't very clear. It'd help if you edited your question to include the code from your two javascript files and try to explain explicitly what problem you're having, i.e., what the "conflict" is. It might also be helpful to open up the [devtools console](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/#top_of_page) and look at any errors that might appear there OR to do some basic debugging to make sure things are working as expected

Comment: `onload` as in `window.onload`? Or are you attaching `onload` to the script tag? Some other tag? Still not sure what you're asking, but if you're having problems with one of your scripts overriding the `onload` function of the other script, then you should use [`window.addEventListener('load', fn)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) or simply just omit the listeners altogether and move your script tags to the bottom of your body tag to ensure they run after the rest of the body is loaded. Scripts are loaded and executed in the order they're included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the conversation we had in the comments, I think I understand what you're asking here and what you mean by "conflicting."

To create a simple example, you have two js files that both use `window.onload`. The purpose of `window.onload` is to run the function you assign to it when the window is loaded.

Say you have two JS files:

`A.js`

```
window.onload = function(){
  console.log("File A")
}
```

and `B.js`

```
window.onload = function(){
  console.log("File B")
}
```

The problem is that `window.onload` can only have one function assigned to it a time. If you run the following code snippet you'll see that only the string `"File B"` gets logged to the console.

```html
<script>
window.onload = function(){
  console.log("File A")
}
</script>

<script>
window.onload = function(){
  console.log("File B")
}
</script>
```

Note that the order here **IS** important. Scripts are loaded and executed from top to bottom in your HTML whether they're linked or written inline. Where it gets confusing is because of Javascript's [asynchronous behavior](https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee) but that's something you'll get an intuition for as you learn.

You'll usually want to use [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener), on in this case `window.addEventListener` which will let you add multiple events to the same target (the window being the target in this case, but targets can include almost any element on the page).

Note how the below example now logs both strings.

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  console.log("File A")
})
</script>

<script>
window.addEventListener('load', function(){
  console.log("File B")
})
</script>
```

However, you potentially do not need to use the `load` event at all. It was historically used as a way to create a scope for modules/libraries/tools so that 3rd party code wouldn't have global variables that conflict just because they use the same name. This is sort of an advanced topic, so I won't go into detail, but using the `window.onload` event or the `addEventListener` variant have for the most part been replaced with using an [`Immediately Invoked Function Expressions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE)

Comment: IIFE does not replace the `onload` event. The `onload` event is necessary to wait for all elements on the page to exist before operating on them. What replaces the `onload` event is placing your script tag at the end of the document inside body instead of inside head (this started being recommended by people like Yahoo and Google around 2007). But if you are still including your scripts in the document head then you still need `onload`

Comment: ... More recently `onload` became unnecessary due to generating 100% of the content in javascript (React, Angular etc.) - again, it was replaced by a virtual DOM + js rendering engine - not IIFE (indeed you don't need IIFE at all if you don't want to use it)